# How to make basic REST API calls using a browser

Tags: json, api, rest, http

I am trying to get started with REST API calls by seeing how to format the API calls using a browser.  Most examples I have found online use SDKs or just return all fields for a request.

For example, I am trying to use [the Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) to view [track information](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks).

To start, I've made a simple request in the browser as follows `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=31a9f4a3314c219bd5c79393a8a569ec` which returns a bunch of info about the track in JSON format

(e.g. `{"kind":"track","id":13158665,"created_at":"2011/04/06 15:37:43 ...}`)

Is it possible to only to get returned the "created_at" value using the browser?   I apologize if this question is basic, but I don't know what keywords to search online.  Links to basic guides would be nice, although I would prefer to stay out of using a specific SDK for the time being.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, it's really hard to answer such question since it depends on the Web APIs. I mean if the API supports to return only a subset of fields, you could but if not, you will receive all the content. From what I saw on the documentation, it's not possible. The filters only allow you to get a subset of elements and not control the list of returned fields within elements.

Notice that you have a great application to execute HTTP requests (and also REST) in Chrome: **Postman**. This allows to execute all HTTP methods and not only GET ones and controls the headers and sent content and also see what is received back.

If you use Firefox, **Firebug** provides a similar thing.

To finish, you could have a look at this link to find out hints about the way Web APIs work and are designed: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you and I answered you question,
Thierry

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the browser bar you can utilize REST endpoints that respond to a GET message.  That is what you are doing when you hit that URI, you are sending an HTTP GET message to that server and it is sending back a JSON.

You are not always guaranteed a JSON, or anything when hitting a known REST endpoint. What each endpoint returns when hit with a GET is specific to how it was built.  In that case, it is built to return a JSON, but some may return an HTML page.  In my personal experience, most endpoints that utilize JSON returns expect you to process that object in a computer fashion and don't give you a lot of options to get a specific field of the JSON. [Here is a good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript) on how to process JSON utilizing JavaScript.

You can utilize REST clients (such as the [Advanced REST Client for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US)) to craft HTTP POST and PUT if a specific REST endpoint has the functionality built in to receive data and do something with it. For example, a lot of wiki style REST endpoints will allow you to create a page with a specifically crafted HTTP POST with either specific header information, URI parameters or a JSON as part of it.

Answer (score 4):

you can install DHC client app in your chrome and send request like put or get